# How much jsp is there in spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, rest, spring-mvc

I am planning to build web app in spring mvc , hibernate.

i want to ask do i need to jave jsp knowledge for that.

or can i use separate thing like REST so that i can code the view without pages.

if yes , then how much in details JSP i need to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring MVC is built on top of the Servlet/JSP APIs, which in turn uses JSP to render views. However, it also provides support for alternative view layers such as [Freemarker, Velocity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity) and even XSLT (urgh), if you don't want to use JSP.

I advise you to bite the bullet and learn JSP.  It's not that hard.

I don't see where REST comes into this, though, that that nothing to do with view rendering. The server still has to output *something*.  Perhaps you're referring to direct output of XML and/or JSON?  Spring MVC [does that too](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-xml-marshalling), and that doesn't require a view layer.

Comment: IN your opinion which thing should i use. i want to use extensive jquery in html , so with respect to that should i go for jsp , velocity , freemaker or anythging else. which thing is more used in enterprise

Comment: @Name: JSP is the Java industry-standard view layer, and works just fine. I recommend starting with that.

Comment: Industry-standard? I'd say ex-Industry-standard, as discussed in [Bozho's recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845032/wheres-the-official-jsp-tutorial)

Comment: @Sean: What Sun/Oracle *wants* the standard to be, and what everyone actually uses, are two very different things :) The vast majority of appservers out there are Tomcat or J2EE 1.4 servers, and JSP rules therein.